# Problema con height del navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

buenas!
Estoy realizando un portfolio y me sucede que al estar en desktop, el menu se ve bien. Una vez que clickeo el toggle, aparece el menu, pero luego si sigo bajando, es como que desaparece.

Por otro lado, en version mobile, me sucede que el menu se rompe. La (mala) solución que encontre fue darle height: 100% al navbar,y eso lo "repara" pero... eso me trae de problema que si no esta desplegado el menu, al pasar el inspector de elementos me aparece como que esta arriba de todo por lo tanto si quiero seleccionar texto o algo no me deja.

He probado con z-index y muchas cosas pero no pude, hasta que me decidi a escribir.
Espero no haber confundido mucho con mi escrito y dejo aqui el codepen para que puedan visualizar. https://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/KKdzmJV?editors=0110

Ojala puedan ayudarme

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

amigo yo te recomiendo que el nav lo coloques como un contenedor y el resto del codigo lo coloques en otro contenedor por ejemplo:

```
<div class="contenedor-nav">

    <!-- Acá va tu nav -->

</div>


<div class="contenedor-resto-pag">

    <!-- Acá el resto de la web -->

</div>
```

Y te recomiendo que trabajes la mayoría de parámetros en tu web con % para hacer mucho mas fácil su responsive